# Why are these c++ tuples not equal?

Tags: c++, tuples

If each of these string variables in the left portion certainly contain their literal equivalents in the latter, then why do I not get my message?

```
if (make_tuple(this->currentState, inputSymbol, stackTop) == make_tuple("q0", "a", "0"))
    cout << "These tuples are equal" << endl;
```

The reason I ask is because I am using a map with a tuple as the key and when I try to use find(), it behaves as if the key does not exist in the mapping, which I am certain it does because I went through the map using an iterator and displayed all of the keys (each element in the tuples). I suspect that the error has something to do with the above code because those should be equal but they are not. (I am using map.find(make_tuple(blah, blah, blah)) and comparing that to the map.end()) Thoughts?

Comment: So currentState, inputSymbol and stackTop are all `std::string`'s?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear about that

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please give us a **complete** example program. Show us exactly what these variables contain. If this line truly is the culprit you should be able to give us fully self-contained 5 or 10 line program that shows the problem.

Comment: Some non-printable characters? Be on the lookout for `\n` in particular: iot would manifest as funny format or empty lines in your iterator's walk output.

Comment: Maybe, you assume a char pointer compare being a strcmp?

Comment: @BenjafosaurWilfong No problem here:  http://ideone.com/VgaNMP  So what is different at that link and your program that would make the same code snippet you provided work differently?  Is it that those values are *not* the same in the tuple comparison?  All we have are variables in your post, and we don't know really what's behind them.  The link shows that if truly, the values are equal, then the template comparison shows equality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best guess at your question:

```
const char input[] = "hello";
if (std::make_tuple(input) == std::make_tuple("hello")) {
    // won't get here
    std::cout << "equal\n";
}
```

The reason is that `tuple<>::operator==` is just element-wise equality. In this case, we have two `tuple<const char*>`, but while the strings they point to are the same, the actual pointers themselves are different, and we're just comparing the pointers.

If you want this to work, you'll need the left-hand-side to be a type that has an `operator==` that does the right thing. Like, say, `std::string`:

```
const char input[] = "hello";
if (std::make_tuple(std::string(input)) == std::make_tuple("hello")) {
    // now it happens
    std::cout << "equal\n";
}
```

Or, since you're using a `std::map`, you will **not** want to use the default `tuple<>::operator<` and instead provide your own that uses [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)  instead of the raw pointer `<`.